# Regex to allow certain special characters - escape issue

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I've working on a javascript regex that I intend to use with the jquery validate plugin (I'll add this as an additional method). It must (among other rules):

1. test if at least one of the following special characters is entered:

   ```
   !, ", #, $, %, &, ', (, ), *, +,-, .,/, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, @, [, \, ], ^, _, `, {, |, }, ~
   ```
2. not allow 3 consecutive identical characters:

passed:

```
aa
99
++
```

not passed:

```
aaa
999
+++
```

The problem with my regex is that is having problem with these mentioned rules:
I think the issue is related to escaping and I've tried escaping + and - to no avail. Can anyone help! This is my regex: http://regexr.com/3ack3

Comment: Are the rules independent or do both have to be satisfied for `passed`?

Comment: Please post your regex here.  I understand you are developing on regexr.com, but it will also help here if you say what language / regex style you are targeting specifically (presuming you want to use it outside of regexr.com).

Comment: They are independent. This regex is for a password validation, so the password may contain (if desired) the special characters above. However, repetition of the same character up to 3 times is not allowed. Hope this is now clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @1203_dube. I edited my original post with your suggestion. This is going to be used with jquery validate as an additional method.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those requirements where you can really simplify your life by using multiple regexes, rather than trying to cram all the logic into one complex regex with many assertions. Here's some JavaScript that implements your requirement:

```
var specialCharRegex = /[!"#$%&'()*+.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~-]/;
var threeConsecutiveRegex = /(.)\1\1/;

var input = prompt();
if (specialCharRegex.test(input) && !threeConsecutiveRegex.test(input)) {
    alert('passed');
} else {
    alert('failed');
} // end if
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8609xv2/

Some notes on the trickier points:

- inside the bracket expression, the following four special characters had to be backslash-escaped: `/[\]`. (Forward slash because it delimits the regex, backslash because it's the escape character, and the brackets because they delimit the bracket expression.)
- inside the bracket expression, the dash had to be moved to the end, because otherwise it would likely specify a character range. When at the end, it never specifies a range, so it's always safer to put it there.

This modular approach also benefits maintainability, as you will more easily be able to make changes (modify/add/remove regexes, or change the if-test logic) at a later point in time.

Another benefit is that you could test each regex independently, which could allow you to provide a more accurate error message to the user, as opposed to just saying something like "invalid password".

**Edit:** Here's how you can whitelist the chars that are accepted in the input:

```
var specialCharRegex = /[!"#$%&'()*+.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~-]/;
var threeConsecutiveRegex = /(.)\1\1/;
var nonWhitelistCharRegex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~-]/;

var input = prompt();
if (specialCharRegex.test(input) && !threeConsecutiveRegex.test(input) && !nonWhitelistCharRegex.test(input)) {
    alert('passed');
} else {
    alert('failed');
} // end if
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8609xv2/2/

Comment: thanks @bgoldst. One thing I noticed though is that when you start the string with a special character not listed as accepted, it passes still. Try with `°654321Ab**` The bullet (°) sign is not valid. Is there a way to restrict this?

Comment: That string is passing because the asterisk is an accepted special char. If you remove the two asterisks, then it fails.

Comment: Do you also want to reject a set of characters, including the bullet sign? You could add that requirement with another regex (which would be negated in the if-test, e.g. `var rejectedCharsRegex = /[°]/; if (... && !rejectedCharsRegex.test(input))`).

Comment: Thanks for your last piece of code. Can you explain a bit why the ° sign is accepted? I thought that when you limit the regex to allow certain special characters, it sticks to only those, not accepting others. Great help by the way. :)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. What you're looking for is an additional requirement to *whitelist* the set of acceptable chars. The first requirement you specified in your question is worded in such a way that it means you want to require *at least one* special char, but it does not limit what chars are acceptable in the input.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?(.)\1{2})(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*()_=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?+-]).{8,20}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD8sH3/3)

You might be able to shorten it using:

```
^(?!.*?(.)\1{2})(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[\W_]).{8,20}$
```

i.e. using non-word property `\W` instead of listing each and every special character.

Comment: Those are from OP's demo link actually

Comment: The code is accepting as valid this: `aabcdefg9999Hi*` Number 9 is repeating.

Comment: I am on mobile so unable to test it. Will get back to my computer in few minutes.

Comment: @Adorablepolak: Check my updated regex and new demo. It is not allowing `aabcdefg9999Hi*` now.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*[!"#$%&'()*+,,\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~-])(?!.*(.)\1\1).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/10

You need a `positive lookahead` to check for `special characters`.

And

A `negative lookahead` to check if a character is is there `3` times.